# Why are these red dots appearing in my viewport?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I'm following Andrew Price's (Blenderguru's) latest donut tutorial series but I'm a bit confused as to why I'm seeing all of these red dots in my viewport render, when Andrew's version isn't.

We're both using the Cycles render engine using GPU and both have viewport sampling of 32. The light object lightning the scene is white and there are no objects in the scene that could be adding to this reddish colour.

I have a feeling my node settings are incorrect so I've attached a picture of these at the bottom.

Here's the comparison between the two...

**My Donut:**

[image: donut with red dots]

**Andrew's Donut:**

[image]

These are the nodes I'm using (which are the same as Andrews):

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red dots are appearing because of Subsurface Scattering (SSS), or translucency. When you turn on SSS in Cycles, there will be strange colored dots unless you render at a higher sample count. Some possible ways to solve your problem are

- Reduce the amount of SSS by adjusting the Subsurface slider.
- Adjust the Subsurface Raduis

Because doughnuts are usually made of bread, you should have SSS values close to `0.05`, and SSS Radius values close to `(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)`